# Proguard with AbstractModule

Tags: android, maven, module, proguard

The following exception is being thrown when my android app starts up;

```
can't instantiate class com.project.modules.ClientServicesModule; no empty constructor
```

My module class looks like the following;

```
public class ClientServicesModule
    extends AbstractModule
{

    private Context context;

    public ClientServicesModule(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(){

       ....

      bind(new TypeLiteral<Dao<City, Integer>>()
        {
        }).toProvider(new DaoProvider<City, Integer>(OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class).getConnectionSource(), City.class))
            .in(Singleton.class);

       ...
       }
}
```

My Proguard file:

```
-target 1.6

-verbose
-dump ../bin/class_files.txt
-printseeds ../bin/seeds.txt
-printusage ../bin/unused.txt
-printmapping ../bin/mapping.txt

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-ignorewarnings
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,Signature

-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.joda.**
-dontwarn roboguice.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn twitter.**
-dontnote
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb

# roboguice's jar has testing classes in it which don't resolve because the Android testing classes aren't available for non-testing
-dontwarn roboguice.test.RoboActivityUnitTestCase
-dontwarn roboguice.test.RoboUnitTestCase

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends com.google.inject.AbstractModule
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-keep class roboguice.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {  
    public <init> (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * { 
    public <init> (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
}
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable { static android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* { public static <fields>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
    public void *(android.view.View); 
}
-keepclassmembers class * { 
    @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
    @com.google.inject.Inject <fields>;
    @javax.annotation.Nullable <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    void *(net.eworldui.videouploader.events.*);
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    void *(roboguice.activity.event.*);
}
```

My ProGuard config works if I add an empty constructor but then the dao wont load as null is being passed into the database helper.

If I remove the ProGuard step from my pom.xml everything works as expected.

The question is how to enable proguard so that the module class can startup with the context being passed in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following line to your Proguard.config:

```
-keep public class * extends com.project.modules.ClientServicesModule { 
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
 }
```

and see if the error persists

EDIT:

you can keep a whole namespace by defining:

```
-keep class com.project.modules.** {*;}
```

If that works, you can try to exclude others you don't need after that. Have a look at my first edit, too

Comment: Didnt work and I assume the line -keep public class * extends com.google.inject.AbstractModule would have taken care of this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that `ClientServicesModule` is in fact a subclass of `AbstractServerModule`..., they have a different namespace, too. Yo can keep a whole namespace, just look at my edit

Comment: Works a treat...guess Im going to have to build up my testing slowly with proguard as got more errors...